# homeomorphism over zariski topology becomes a homeomorphism over usual topology?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

a semicubical parabola $L$ in $\mathbb C^2$ is given by $y^2=x^3$.

I showed that a bijective function $f\colon\mathbb C \to L$ defined by $t \mapsto (t^2, t^3)$ becomes a homeomorphism regarding the Zariski topolgy.

But it doens't seem clear to me whether $f$ is a homeomorphism with the usual topoology on the complex numbers. Anyone could give me some proof?

Comment: The p.s. question seems totally unrelated, please ask it separately

Comment: Ok that seems betteer

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is much easier to show the result for the Euclidean topology in a direct way: The map $f$ defined above is continous with regard to the Euclidean topology. Its inverse is the map

$$g: L \longrightarrow \mathbb C, \ g(x,y):= y/x \ for\ (x,y) \neq (0,0) \ and \ g(0,0):= 0.$$

To show that $g$ is continous in $(0,0)\in L$:

$$lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \ (y/x)^2 = lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \ (y^2/x^2) = lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \ x= 0,$$

hence also $lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \ (y/x) = 0$, q.e.d.